# how to load audio from Google Storage/ how to read audio from google storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, librosa

I save my audio file in google storage in wav format, but when i try to load the audio using google colab, i not manage to done it.

Below the example i used to load audio from google storage.

```
import numpy as np
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
import io
from google.cloud import storage
import os
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = "fundpro" #project_id
BUCKET = 'parli-2020' #bucket_name
gcs = storage.Client()
bucket = gcs.get_bucket(BUCKET)
import speech_recognition as sr
for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix='speech/Transcribe'):
    filename = 'gs://parli-2020/' + blob.name
    X, sample_rate = librosa.core.load(filename)
```

but it shows this error;

```
filename cannot be found.[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If anyone could help me out I'd be very thankful...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Librosa doesn't support GCS protocol, as explained in the [source code documentation](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/da3b231518978304588a873fc7ec0cbead2a7610/librosa/core/audio.py#L64)

So, to use a path compliant solution, you can use gcsfs library

```
from fs import open_fs
...
...
for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix='speech/Transcribe'):
    filename = 'gs://parli-2020/' + blob.name
    gcsfs = open_fs(filename)
    X, sample_rate = librosa.core.load(gcsfs)
```

Comment: it shows this error. "UnsupportedProtocol: protocol 'gs' is not supported".